# How can I trigger lambda when there are no uploaded files in s3?

Tags: python, boto3

I want to check if any files got uploaded in S3.

If there were no file uploads in the last 10 hours, I want to trigger a lambda that can be notified by SNS.

How can I trigger lambda when there were no uploaded file in S3 in last certain hour?

How could I trigger the lambda when there were no files uploaded in the last hour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this at any interval you wish to get the last key and when it was uploaded. From there you can make calculations as to whether or not you want to be notified. It will read all objects, so if you have a lot of objects it goes against your read_object() counts so it could become expensive depending on how you configure this.

```
bucket = 'your_bucket'
prefix = 'your_prerix/if_needed/'

tuple_list = []
paginator = s3sr.meta.client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
# use Delimiter to limit search to that level of hierarchy
for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/'):
    lastmodified=[content['LastModified'] for content in page.get('Contents')]
    tuples = [(content['Key'], content['LastModified']) for content in page.get('Contents')]
    # print('keys in page: ', len(keys))
    tuple_list.extend(tuples)
tuple_list.sort(key=lambda r: r[1])
last_file = tuple_list[-1][0]
last_timestamp = tuple_list[-1][1]
print(last_file, last_timestamp)
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your help..
I will study with your code..

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know when the most recent object was uploaded to S3. That's not a trivial task for a bucket with lots of objects. You could configure S3 to trigger a Lambda function to run every time an object is uploaded and write a 'last-uploaded-time' timestamp to DynamoDB.

Next, you need to schedule the checking of the 'last-uploaded-time' timestamp. You could do that with a CloudWatch/EventBridge scheduled event. Run a Lambda function on a schedule, e.g. every hour.

Comment: Hello, jarmod,
Actually, I am not developer, but system engineer..
I understand the JOB logic you advised to me.....
But.. can you give me some more hint..?}
How can i write timestamp with lambda when triggerd..?
just give me little sample.. if you may..